# Create Sections in Ghost CMS

Tags: wordpress, ghost-blog

Is it possible to create sections (a block of content that span horizontally across the page) like the following (e.g,. Premium, User Friendly Features, Our Users Love Us) (this page is from https://generatepress.com) using Ghost?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ghost CMS can't help you to create sections like this. You can create sections like this only in your theme. For this you have to edit your theme and then upload it to the ghost.